# How to target all woocommerce categories that don't have any subcategories in them?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy

I want to target all pages (product categories) that are displaying the products themselves.

My woocommerce settings set to show only categories/subcategories (unless there are none) and then by default the products grid is displayed on the page.

`is_product_category()` function doesn't help since it also targets the parent categories which don't have direct products in them.

Most of my categories that don't any subcategories in them are grandchildren categories if it matters for the answer.

How can I achieve it and to use it in woocommerce hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_products_will_display()`. This function returns `true` if the current shop page is going to display products. This will be the case if your shop pages are set to display products or subcategories *and* products, but it will be `false` if the shop pages are set to display subcategories only, and the current category has subcategories.

```
if ( woocommerce_products_will_display() ) {
    // Products are showing.
} else {
    // Products are not showing.
}
```

The `woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode()` is similar, but can let you know whether subcategories are also displaying:

```
switch ( woocommerce_get_loop_display_mode() ) {
    case 'products':
        // Products are displaying.
        break;
    case 'subcategories':
        // Subcategories are displaying.
        break;
    case 'both':
        // Products and subcategories are displaying.
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome and it did help me! Thank you. But if these woo functions didn't exist for example (or might be renamed/deleted in next woo versions) How else would you check if the current displayed category has subcategories in it? I mean not related to your woocommerce store settings.

Comment: Regular taxonomy archives don't ever display subcategories, so you'd never need to do it for the same reason. But if you did the only way is to use `get_terms()` with the `parent` argument set to the current term ID to see if any exist. The current taxonomy won't have any information about how many children it has.